# Change django-messages-to-bootstrap-notify settings

Tags: django, notifications, bootstrap-notify

I'm using [django-messages-to-bootstrap-notify](https://github.com/DCOD-OpenSource/django-messages-to-bootstrap-notify) to show notification on my django project. How can I change it's default settings to show my customized notifications?

Comment: What kind of customized notifications ? Please give additional context to your question. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I mean animation settings such ad fade-in and fade-out. I can change them in original package in me env folder . But I'm looking for a solution to change it from my project.